# Typescript: Is it possible to indicate that Promise resolves and rejects with a specific type?

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-typings

```typescript
const myFunc = (value: boolean): Promise<boolean | Error> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!value) {
      reject(new Error("error msg"));
      return;
    }

    resolve(true);
  });
};
```

In the given example the Promise always resolves to `true` and always rejects with an `Error`. But the `Promise<boolean | Error>` type declaration is not that specific. Is it possible to "tell" TypeScript that if the Promise resolves the value is always a boolean (or even better - `true`) and if it rejects the value is an instance of `Error`?

Comment: The error type is always `any`. (so no way to change the type of parameter passed to catch).You can return the boolean literal `true`: `Promis<true>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the type of the error with the current type definition. The type of the error is always `any`. This is obvious looking at the definition of `catch`:

```
catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
```

The argument `reason` of the `onrejected` callback is `any`.

You can use the boolean literal type `true` to represent the fact that the value can be only true

```
const myFunc = (value: boolean): Promise<true> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!value) {
        reject(new Error("error msg"));
        return;
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
  };

myFunc(true)
    .then(r=> r) // r is typed as true
```

One workaround, although not a great one, is to use the result of the promise for both error and success cases.

```
const myFunc = (value: boolean): Promise<true | Error> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!value) {
            resolve(new Error("error msg"));
            return;
        }
        resolve(true);
    });
};

myFunc(true)
    .then(r =>  // r true | Error
    {
        if(r === true){
            r // r is true 
        }else{
            r.message // r is Error 
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation. So the TL;DR answer is: "No, it's not possible".

Comment: @wube Yes, but just answering 'Nope' seemed like a magnet for downvotes :P

Comment: It's just a wrap-up, not an accusation. Of course, I appreciate the answer :)